# Calculate weeks between date range and days in each weeks between the range

Tags: r, dplyr

Input Dataframe

```
   ID   RID PID check_in         check_out
10240   1   1   13-08-2014 9.30  14-08-2014 9.30
10240   2   1   16-08-2014 9.30  17-08-2014 9.30
10240   3   2   18-09-2012 9.30  25-09-2012 9.30
10240   4   1   25-09-2012 9.30  30-09-2012 9.30
10240   5   1   27-01-2015 22.30 27-02-2015 20.30
```

Expecting Output

```
  ID    RID PID check_in               check_out     Weekite Weekstart  Weekgrp Days
10240   1   1   13-08-2014 9.30      14-08-2014 9.30    1   10-08-2014  10-08-2014  1
10240   2   1   16-08-2014 9.30      17-08-2014 9.30    1   10-08-2014  10-08-2014  1
10240   3   2   18-09-2012 9.30      25-09-2012 9.30    1   16-09-2012  16-09-2012  7
10240   4   1   25-09-2012 9.30      30-09-2012 9.30    1   23-09-2012  23-09-2012  5
10240   5   1   27-01-2015 22.30    27-02-2015 20.30    5   25-01-2015  25-01-2015  5
10240   5   1   27-01-2015 22.30    27-02-2015 20.30    5   25-01-2015  01-02-2015  7
10240   5   1   27-01-2015 22.30    27-02-2015 20.30    5   25-01-2015  08-02-2015  7
10240   5   1   27-01-2015 22.30    27-02-2015 20.30    5   25-01-2015  15-02-2015  7
10240   5   1   27-01-2015 22.30    27-02-2015 20.30    5   25-01-2015  22-02-2015  5
```

However I am not getting output as expected.

Below is my code:

```
output_df <- weektest %>% 
  group_by(ID, RID,PID) %>%
  mutate(Weekite = ceiling(difftime(strptime(check_out, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                            strptime(check_in, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),units="weeks"))) %>%
  mutate(Weekstart = as.Date(cut(check_in,
                                 breaks = "week",
                                 start.on.monday = FALSE))) %>%

  mutate(Weekgrp = list(seq(Weekstart[1], by="week", length.out=Weekite[1]))) %>%
  unnest %>%

  mutate(Days = if(n() > 1)
                       case_when(

                         row_number() == 1L ~ day(Weekgrp[2]) - day(check_in),
                         row_number() == n() ~ day(check_out) - day(Weekgrp[n()]),
                         row_number() != 1L | n() ~ day(Weekgrp[n()]) - day(Weekgrp[n()-1]),
                         )
              else day(check_out)- day(check_in)

  )
```

Line `row_number() == 1L ~ day(Weekgrp[2]) - day(check_in)` gives incorrect `Days` as `-26`.

Please help.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some details on the variables that you want to generate (i.e. `Weekite`, `Weekstart`, `Weekgrp`), instead of having us work them out based on your code.

Comment: @MauritsEvers actualy I am interested in Weekgrp which gives me dates of the start of the week between the given date range and number of days falling in each week. Weekite and Weekstart are generated to get Weekgrp. They are not required.

Comment: So `Days` is just the time difference between `check_out` and `check_in`? I'm still not sure what `Weekgrp` is supposed to be. It seems to coincide with `Weekstart`, but only for some entries?

Comment: For example in check_in 27-01-2015 and check_out 27-02-2015 their are 31 days.
However these two dates has 5 distinct weeks in between. So if I want to view the days weekly between these date range then I would need the week and days.
Now 27/01/2015 falls in Week 25/01/2015 so the number of days in this week would be 5.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about the logic behind `weekgrp`?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the probable solution:

```
output_df <- weektest %>% 
  group_by(ID, RID,PID) %>%
  mutate(Weekstart = as.Date(cut(check_in,
                                 breaks = "week",
                                 start.on.monday = FALSE))) %>% 
  mutate(Weekite = ceil(difftime(strptime(check_out, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                 strptime(Weekstart, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),units="weeks"))) %>%  
  mutate(Weekgrp = list(seq(Weekstart[1], by="week", length.out=Weekite[1]))) %>%
  unnest %>%  
  mutate(Days = if(n() > 1)
    case_when(
      row_number() == 1L ~ as.numeric(Weekgrp[2] - as.Date(strptime(check_in,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))),
      row_number() == n() ~ as.numeric(as.Date(strptime(check_out,format = "%Y-%m-%d")) - Weekgrp[n()]),
      row_number() != 1L | n() ~ as.numeric(Weekgrp[n()] - Weekgrp[n()-1])
    )
    else as.numeric(as.Date(strptime(check_out,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))- as.Date(strptime(check_in,format = "%Y-%m-%d")))    
  )  
output_df$Weekite <- NULL
output_df$Weekstart <- NULL
```